# String Manipulation using php

Tags: php

I have a string like this

```
$str=44797675962044781781414912/04/2012
```

- First 12 digit: 447976759620 is the phone number
- Next 12 digit: 447817814149 is the server code

and rest are the date

#### I am trying to get it like  this:

```
echo substr($str,0,12).'<br/>';
echo substr($str,12,24).'<br/>';
$tempRest["receivedtime"]=substr($pieces[0],-10);
```

Getting this weird out put :

```
   44797675962
   12/04/2012
   44778691004444781781414912/04/2012
```

What can I do. Any help?

### EDITED :

#### Original code :

```
  function GetSoapReturnArray() {
 $classmap = array('MyWSDLStructure' => 'MyComplexDataType');
 $m_wsdl = 'https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl';
  $m_arr_soapclient = array('trace' => true, 'exceptions' => true);


  $soap_client_handle = new SoapClient($m_wsdl, $m_arr_soapclient);
  $soap_result = $soap_client_handle->peekMessages('telab048', 'Qwerty12', 40, '', 1);;

  $str=NULL;
  
  foreach ($soap_result as $soapArrayData)
  {
    $pieces = preg_split('/[ ]/', $soapArrayData);

  $str=$pieces[0];
    //echo $str.'<br/>';
    
    echo substr($str, 0, 12) . '<br />';
    echo substr($str, 12, 12) . '<br />';
  }
}


}
  GetSoapReturnArray();
```

Comment: You get `$str` from where? XML?

Comment: seems its XML response. Did you try DOM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter to [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) is the length, not the ending index. Pass `12` instead of `24`.

```
echo substr($str, 0, 12) . '<br />';
echo substr($str, 12, 12) . '<br />';
$tempRest["receivedtime"] = substr($pieces[0], 24);
```

Comment: no luck the output is like this :44797675962044781781414912/04/2012
<
sourcemsisdn

Comment: the string is coming from a webservice..but this shouldn't be the problem..let me show u what the original code is...

Comment: @minitech: Take [a look at sscanf doing this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10252739/367456).

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju: You figured out what the string contained by using `echo $str . '<br />';`, right? Well, it may have contained XML that your browser did not display (it being part of the structure). Try "View Source" on that output, and I think you'll find some unexpected things.

Comment: ya it was returning xml..i jsut made a parser and that worked..thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are having problems because `$str` is not just a string it contains `HTML` tags use `strip_tags` to filter all the html tags ...

Try

```
    foreach ( $soap_result as $soapArrayData ) {
        $pieces = preg_split ( '/[ ]/', $soapArrayData );

        $str = $pieces [0];
        $str = trim ( $str );
        $str = strip_tags ( $str );
        echo substr ( $str, 0, 12 ) . '<br />'; //Phone Number
        echo substr ( $str, 12, 12 ) . '<br />'; // Server Code
        echo substr ( $str, 24, 10 ) . '<br />'; //Time
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you have [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf):

```
$r = sscanf($str, '%12s%12s%s', $phone, $server, $date);
```

Output (`var_dump($phone, $server, $date);`):

```
string(12) "447976759620"
string(12) "447817814149"
string(10) "12/04/2012"
```